# Scraping multiple websites and putting a table from each into its own CSV file

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I have a text file filled with links that I need to scrape. There is a table in each website that i need to get and save in its own CSV file and I have this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import csv
import urllib2

def stir_the_soup():
    player_links = open('player_links.txt', 'r')
    player_ID_nums = open('player_ID_nums.txt', 'r')
    id_nums = [x.rstrip('\n') for x in player_ID_nums]
    idx = 0
    for url in player_links:
        player_link = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        bs = BeautifulSoup(player_link, 'lxml')
        table_id = ""
        if url[-12] == 'b':
            table_id = "batting"
        elif url[-12] == 'p':
            table_id = "pitching"
    table = str(bs.find('table', {'id' : (table_id + '_gamelogs')}))
    df = pd.read_html(table)
    df2 = df[idx]
    df2.to_csv(path_or_buf=("%s.csv", id_nums[idx]), sep=',')
    idx += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    stir_the_soup()
```

The id_nums list is a list of names I want for each CSV file.

I am getting this error however:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Not sure what is going wrong, I know read_html() saves a tuple of dataframes so I was trying to get each one and save it into its own CSV. I searched around and can't find a good answer to this. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you are passing a tuple to **path_or_buf** attribute. This throws an AttributeError. Change ',' for '%' could solve your problem:

```
df2.to_csv(path_or_buf=("%s.csv" % id_nums[idx]), sep=',')
```